# EXEC sp_changemergearticle for ALL articles

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, replication

Is there a way I can change a property for all articles in my replication at the same time?

So instead of:

```
EXEC sp_changemergearticle 
@publication = 'MyPublication', 
@article = 'MyArticle', 
@property = 'published_in_tran_pub', 
@value = 'true';

EXEC sp_changemergearticle 
@publication = 'MyPublication', 
@article = 'MyArticle1', 
@property = 'published_in_tran_pub', 
@value = 'true';

EXEC sp_changemergearticle 
@publication = 'MyPublication', 
@article = 'MyArticle2', 
@property = 'published_in_tran_pub', 
@value = 'true';

EXEC sp_changemergearticle 
@publication = 'MyPublication', 
@article = 'MyArticle3', 
@property = 'published_in_tran_pub', 
@value = 'true';
```

I want to change the property @published_in_tran_pub for all articles in one query. Something like:

```
EXEC sp_changemergearticle 
@publication = 'MyPublication', 
@article = 'ALL ARTICLES', 
@property = 'published_in_tran_pub', 
@value = 'true';
```

So I want to change the @published_in_tran_pub property for ALL articles by one single statement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right,

I may have this wrong (again) - but seeming as I dont know anything more than you want to call a sproc a lot - you could loop through your set of articles and pass them to your sproc;

```
-- I presume you can get a list of distinct Articles - you dont have to use 
-- a tmp table if they already exist - use that table instead

SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Article) as Row_ID,
                Article
INTO #Tmp
FROM MyArticleTable -- Dont know what this is called
WHERE publication = @publication -- only pick the articles you want to use for this sproc call

DECLARE @i int = 1
DECLARE @currentArticle varchar(max) 

WHILE @i <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Tmp)
BEGIN 
    SET @currentArticle = (SELECT Article FROM #Tmp WHERE Row_ID = @i)
    EXEC sp_changemergearticle 
    @publication = 'MyPublication', 
    @article = @currentArticle, 
    @property = 'published_in_tran_pub', 
    @value = 'true'

SET @i = @i+ 1

END
```

Comment: looks good, although it does not work yet. It keeps saying 'executing query' - now already for 5 mins..| to get a list of all articles I can query: SELECT name
FROM SYS.tables
where is_merge_published = 1

Comment: yeah a looping approach wont be fast - how many iterations do you have to do ? you could run a profiler on it to see if there is any indexing or anything you could do - it might be faster to put the data from sys.tables into another table that isnt in the Sys.tables one and see if any indexing strategy can help

Comment: It works men :) - very very nice, I added 'SET @i = @i+ 1' - THANKS A LOT!

Comment: yeah, sorry about that - I just didnt really understand what you wanted initially. Cheers for accepting the answer